# which ordination method will predict grouping based on response variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have several regression models in the format 
m <- lm(y ~ x, dat)

with a different y for each model, but always the same x

For example

```
data(Iris)

m <- lm(Iris$Sepal.L. ~ Sepal.W., data  = Iris)
```

I extracted X and Y from m

```
X <- m$call [2][[1]][[3]]
Y <- m$call [2][[1]][[2]]
```

I then tried to use X and Y for x and y in ggplot

```
ggplot() +  
   geom_point(data = Iris, 
              aes(x = X , y = Y), size = 3)
```

I get the error message:

*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type call. Defaulting to continuous.*

*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type call. Defaulting to continuous.*

*Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (150): x, y, size*

How can I use the call vectors X and Y correctly in ggplot?

*Note: I want to use this code in a loop for a function where I specify a list of Y's  so I dont want to manually write* 
aes(x = Iris$Sepal.W., y = Iris$Sepal.L.)

Comment: What X and Y do you want to plot? It's not clear what `m$call [2][[1]][[3]]` is. When I run it, it get "Sepal.Width", not data

Comment: please check whats saved in `m$call`. A formula can't be plotted. And it is not completely clear what do you want ? Could it be that you want something like this? `ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length , Sepal.Width)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
`

Comment: It would appear OP wants to take the model, and based on that, plot the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My R doesn't come shipped with `Iris` dataset, so I'll use the common `iris`.

```
data(iris)

m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

X <- as.character(m$call [2][[1]][[3]])
Y <- as.character(m$call[2][[1]][[2]])

ggplot() +  
  geom_point(aes(x = iris[, X] , y = iris[, Y]), size = 3)
```

Note a few things. There is no `data` argument in my code because you're not using it since you're passing the data in as vectors (e.g. `iris[, X]`). I'm coercing `X` and `Y` to a character because by default, their class is `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out!

In case it helps others here is the solution. (I need to see change the x and y labels but thats a different issue)

```
ggplot() +  
   geom_point(data = Iris, 
              aes(x = Iris[[X]] , y = Iris[[Y]]), size = 3)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'symbol'`